# How do I create a WCF client using only App.config data?

Tags: c#, wcf, web-config, app-config

I have to connect to a WCF service that does not respond to `svcutil` and won't allow me to create a service reference using the automated tools in Visual Studio - the people who wrote/host the WCF service are extremely security conscious, and have disabled these features (why, I don't know).

I have been given ONLY the configuration data.

My question is: What is the next step towards developing a client that can send WCF requests to this service?

Sorry for the open-ended question ... I'm really stumped here, since this doesn't fit any scenario I can find in online tutorials or TechNet documentation. And I'm new to WCF, so I don't know where to begin.

The return type is a dataset accessible by key/value pair, but I'm uncertain what the C# datatype would be. The documentation I've been given says something like KeyValueOfstringPropertyDto3azeXyb8. EntityDto is mentioned, but I'm not familiar with this (an EntityFramework term?). I've been provided with a list of the columns in the return dataset, but I can't post the column names directly in the question for security reasons.

**Service Name and Binding:**
Name : RecordFindSingle
URL : `http://Server01/RecordFindSingle/RecordFindSingle.svc`
Method : FindSingleRecord
Parameter1 : Source
Parameter2 : RecordNumber

```
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
        <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" maxReceivedMessageSize="2147483647">
          <security mode="TransportCredentialOnly">
            <transport clientCredentialType="Windows" />
            <message clientCredentialType="Username" />
          </security>
        </binding>
       </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
      <endpoint address="http://Server02/RecordFindSingle/RecordFindSingle.svc"
          binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync"
          contract="RecordFindSingle.RecordFindSingle" name="BasicHttpBinding_ITwoWayAsync" />
    </client>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Comment: "have disabled these features (why, I don't know)" - you put the answer to that question in the first part of the sentence: "the people who wrote/host the WCF service are extremely security conscious".  At a glance, it sounds like they have disabled publishing of the WSDL, which will prevent other parties from creating a proxy by simply referencing the WSDL through the URL. I would ask them if they can provide the WSDL for you - if they can, you can use add reference or svcutil to generate a proxy.

Comment: @Tim Makes sense. They won't change any policy for me if it has security implications - even temporarily. As I mentioned, I can't find any good tutorials that show how to connect the client to the service with only this information available. If you would be willing to provide a brief code sample as an answer that can get me moving in the right direction, I'll accept the answer. I've been reading up on HttpWebRequest all day, yet I'm still totally in the dark about how it plays into this ... :( Microsoft documentation fail.

Comment: With nothing but a config file it can be tricky, if it's even possible.  Let me noodle it for a bit and see what I come up with.

Comment: Do you know the parameters and return type of `FindSingleRecord`?

Comment: @brz I just edited my question to include the input parameters. The return type is a dataset accessible by key/value pair, but I'm uncertain what the .NET datatype would be. It says something like KeyValueOfstringPropertyDto3azeXyb8. I've been provided with a list of the columns in the return dataset, but I can't post the column names directly in the question for security reasons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create an Interface and related `DataContract`s that define the servie contract. For example if you have a `Contract` that defines a `FindSingleRecord` method that return an instance of `Record`:

```
[DataContract]
public class Record
{
    [DataMember]
    public string Property1 {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public string Property2 {get;set;}

    // Continue listing all properties ...
}

[ServiceContract]
public interface RecordFindSingle
{
    [OperationContract]
    Record FindSingleRecord(string Source , int RecordNo);
}
```

And then use channel factory to call it:

```
var httpBinding = new BasicHttpBinding()
{
    Security = new BasicHttpSecurity()
    {
        Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.TransportCredentialOnly,
        Message = new BasicHttpMessageSecurity() { ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.UserName },
        Transport = new HttpTransportSecurity() { ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows }
    }
};
ChannelFactory<RecordFindSingle> factory = new ChannelFactory<RecordFindSingle>(httpBinding, new EndpointAddress("http://Server02/RecordFindSingle/RecordFindSingle.svc"));
var channel = factory.CreateChannel();
Record result = channel.FindSingleRecord();
```

Comment: This looks good. Lemme tinker around with this and see if I can get it to work.

Comment: The parameters are Source (required, string) and RecordNumber (required, integer). Can you show me how that would play into this? Would I just put `void FindSingleRecord(string Source, int RecordNumber)` in the RecordFindSingle interface?

Comment: @Giffyguy yes, return type is also important.

Comment: I'm trying to make heads or tails of the vague documentation I've been given. The documentation suggests that the return type is a collection of 1 or more EntityDto's. Is this an EntityFramework term? Should this point me to the return type of the method inside the interface?

Comment: @Giffyguy DTO(Data Transfer Object) is an object that carries data between processes. You have to know what properties that DTO has and create a class that represents that DTO in your client application. See the edited answer.

Comment: That's awesome, I can use my aforementioned list of properties (I called it a column list) to build the DTO class. Let me do some work with this for a little while. I expect this should be enough for me to accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the HttpWebRequest to Call the Web Service at run time. For this you don't have to add any service reference in you solution or Project. In one of my application, I used this functionality to call WCF Web Service from MVC 4 Web API project.

Actually You can send SOAP directly to a WCF service without creating a proxy class. Just create a WebClient object and set “Content-Type” and “SOAPAction” headers then upload the SOAP message to the service. Code look like as follows:

```
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = CreateSoapsEnvelope();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"tempuri.org/IMyService/MyOperation\"");
    var response = client.UploadString("localhost:1234/MyService.svc", data);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}
```

Where CreateSoapsEnvelope() is function which create the Soap Envelope like as which contains the input parameter for Calling web service

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">;
    <s:Body> <OperationName xmlns="tempuri.org/">;
        <Inputparam1>Maged</Inputparam1> <Inputparam2>maged@mail.com</Inputparam2>
</OperationName> </s:Body> </s:Envelope>
```

Comment: Thanks Piyush. If you'd be willing to provide a code sample that could help make this easier to understand, I'd be very grateful. I've been reading about HttpWebRequest all day, and it still doesn't make any sense to me. :(

Comment: Actually You can send SOAP directly to a WCF service without creating a proxy class. Just create a WebClient object and set “Content-Type” and “SOAPAction” headers then upload the SOAP message to the service. Code look like as follows:- using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var data = CreateSoapsEnvelope();
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "text/xml;charset=utf-8");
    client.Headers.Add("SOAPAction", "\"http://tempuri.org/IMyService/MyOperation\"");
    var response = client.UploadString("http://localhost:1234/MyService.svc", data);
    Console.WriteLine(response);
}

Comment: Where CreateSoapsEnvelope() is function which create the Soap Envelope like as which contains the input parameter for Calling web service <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <OperationName xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <Inputparam1>Maged</Inputparam1>
            <Inputparam2>maged@mail.com</Inputparam2>
        </OperationName>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>

Comment: Is this worked for you, or help you to solve the problem

Comment: Possibly, I'm working on it with some other developers where I work as well. I'll let you know how it turns out.